# JQuery AJAX Call with Unicode. Proper way to POST Unicode data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, unicode

I have page that POSTS AJAX to the server, and often the data will be Unicode.

This works most the time, but it appears that sometimes it's breaking and I'm can't seem to find the answer anywhere.  I have been using encodeURI, but I'm not sure that's correct.

Here's a example of the code:

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "SomePage.php",
       data: "val1=" + encodeURI(unicodeVariable) + "&presentation=" + encodeURI(someUnicodeVariable),
       success: function(msg){

       }
     });
```

I'm guessing what's happening is sometimes a Unicode character includes an & that's breaking  it.

What's the correct way to encode Unicode for an AJAX call with JQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a good [link](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) that compares all of the encoding methods.

> Lastly, the **encodeURIComponent()**
>   method should be used in most cases
>   when encoding a single component of a
>   URI. This method will encode certain
>   chars that would normally be
>   recognized as special chars for URIs
>   so that many components may be
>   included. Note that this method does
>   not encode the ' character, as it is a
>   valid character within URIs.

encodeURIComponent() encodes also the "&" symbol:

```
encodeURI("&"); // "&"
encodeURIComponent("&"); // "%26"
```

Or you can just convert this line:

```
data: "val1=" + encodeURI(unicodeVariable) + "&presentation=" + encodeURI(someUnicodeVariable),
```

into an object:

```
data: {
    val1: unicodeVariable,
    presentation: someUnicodeVariable
}
```

And jQuery will automatically make sure the data is encoded, using encodeURIComponent().

Comment: Looks like changing it into an object and making sure the encoding was set to UTF-8 did the trick.  Now all I need to do is figure out why the mdash character isn't getting stored correctly in MySQL.

Comment: @RyanSmith I realize this was over 3 years ago, but did you end up figuring the problem out? I'm dealing with something very similar